# Converter doesn't get called after command executes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command, converters

What this button should do is cycle through the available list of colors and change the background color accordingly.

Initially I had this portion of the view model code in one big/main view model but decided to split it so that each of my user controls would have their own view model. I've tried setting a breakpoint where the OnChangeColor() method executes and I see that the State does indeed change but it does not seem to persist that change to the Converter which therefore does not update the background color of the UI at all.

I have posted code below to which I have made edits and am currently working with to try and figure out what the issue is.

MainWindow

```
    <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CameraListViewModel}">
        <local:MainView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type rep:ReportViewModel}">
        <rep:ReportView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cam:CameraMonitorViewModel}">
        <cam:CameraMonitorView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cam:CameraPropertiesViewModel}">
        <cam:CameraPropertiesView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

View Model:

```
public class CameraPropertiesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{    
    /// <summary>
    /// The current state of the background color
    /// </summary>
    private States _state;

    //Delegate commands for the UI
    private DelegateCommand _changeColorCommand;
    public ICommand ChangeColorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changeColorCommand == null)
            {
                _changeColorCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnChangeColor);
            }
            return _changeColorCommand;

        }
    }

    //All possible background colors
    public enum States
    {
        GREEN,
        YELLOW,
        RED
    }

    //Gets or sets the background color
    public States State
    {
        get
        {
            return _state;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _state, value);
        }
    }

    //Cycle through different colors
    private void OnChangeColor()
    {
        if (State == States.GREEN)
            State = States.RED;
        else if (State == States.RED)
            State = States.YELLOW;
        else if (State == States.YELLOW)
            State = States.GREEN;
    }

}
```

Converter:

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(CameraPropertiesViewModel.States), typeof(Brush))]
public class EnumToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CameraPropertiesViewModel.States state = (CameraPropertiesViewModel.States)value;

        switch (state)
        {
            case CameraPropertiesViewModel.States.GREEN:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            case CameraPropertiesViewModel.States.YELLOW:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            case CameraPropertiesViewModel.States.RED:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainView

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <conv:EnumToColorConverter x:Key="enumToColorConvert"/>
    <cam:CameraPropertiesViewModel x:Key="CPVM" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="{Binding Path=State, Source={StaticResource CPVM},  Converter={StaticResource enumToColorConvert}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition  />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <cam:CamerasListView />

    <cam:CameraPropertiesView Grid.Column="1"/>

    <cam:CameraMonitorView Grid.Row="1" 
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

    <cam:CameraFunctionView Grid.Row="2" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Resources:

```
<local:CameraPropertiesViewModel x:Key="CPVM" />
```

Button

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource circleButton}"
                    Command="{Binding ChangeColorCommand, Source={StaticResource CPVM}}"                     
                    Content="Change Theme" 
                    Width="100" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.Row="2"/>
```

CameraPropertiesView.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:CameraPropertiesViewModel x:Key="CPVM" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="circleButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Canvas Width="50" Height="50">
                                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Camera Details" 
              Height="130" 
              Width="386" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Height="25" 
                   Width="70" 
                   Content="Name" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ConnectedCamera.Name}" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     Height="23" 
                     Width="160"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     IsReadOnly="True" />

            <Label Height="25" 
                   Width="70" 
                   Content="Model" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ConnectedCamera.Model}" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     Height="23" 
                     Width="160"
                     IsReadOnly="True"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Grid.Row="1" />

            <Label Height="25" 
                   Width="70" 
                   Content="Ip Address" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ConnectedCamera.IpAddress}" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     Height="23" 
                     Width="160"
                     IsReadOnly="True" 
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Grid.Row="2" />

            <Button Command="{Binding GenerateReportCommand}"
                    Content="Generate Report" 
                    Width="100" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                    Grid.Column="2" />

            <Button Command="{Binding ArchiveReportCommand}"
                    Content="Archive Report" 
                    Width="100" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.Row="1"/>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource circleButton}"
                    Command="{Binding ChangeColorCommand, Source={StaticResource CPVM}}"                     
                    Content="Change Theme" 
                    Width="100" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.Row="2"/>

        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why there are ViewModel objects? `<cam:CameraPropertiesViewModel x:Key="CPVM" />` and `<local:CameraPropertiesViewModel x:Key="CPVM" />` ?

Comment: What is `MainView` and should we need to see source code of `CameraPropertiesView`? How do you set your ViewModels/DataContext?

Comment: @user1672994 its because the binding property "State" is located in that view model and that is how i'm creating a reference to it

Comment: @V.Leon MainView is essentially a view class that contains a namespaces to child view classes. The view models/datacontext I believe is set as shown in the MainWindow.xaml which is shown above.

Comment: @nwahs - my question was why two different objects of same view model?

Comment: @user1672994 one is located in MainView.xaml and the other is located in CameraPropertiesView.xaml

I'm guessing I should only keep the one in MainView and somehow use it in the CameraPropertiesView?

Comment: Yes, Since your `MainViewModel` already works on `CurrentViewModel` and `DataTemplate` is already defined so you don't need the child view's ViewModel.

Comment: @user1672994 But the thing is if I don't create a namespace and reference it in the CameraPropertiesView.xaml, it won't be able to locate the corresponding command that the button is binded to which is in the CameraPropertiesViewModel.cs

Comment: @nwahs - WPF automatically sets the DataContext of an container element to the appropriate item instance, so that it can be inherited . Remove it and try it, your binding should inherit from top ViewModel object automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue by stripping out the non-important styling, viewmodels, etc.

You are simply missing the Source attribute in the grid binding.
Notice how you have it for the button but not the grid.

```
    <Grid Background="{Binding Path=State, 
        Converter={StaticResource enumToColorConvert}}">
```

Needs to be:

```
    <Grid Background="{Binding Path=State, 
        Converter={StaticResource enumToColorConvert}, 
        Source={StaticResource CPVM}}">
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that fixed part but I've already tried that and it still doesn't work :(

Basically it started off with the State variable originally being in this one big view model called CameraListViewModel and then I decided to split part of that logic into its own user control and view model (CameraPropertyViews & CameraPropertiesViewModel). Now I copied & pasted the related code to this 1 button over from the original view model and commented out the parts in the original. I've checked that it indeed is reading the State value from this new view model.